# Replacement for "NOT IN" for text fields in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying detect a new value for a text field. I am comparing the values of the main query with a subquery of old values. Since the field is a text field, I can't use a "NOT IN" clause.

Here's the data:

```
On Day 1:
infoField: Text1, Text2, Text3
On Day 2:
infoField: Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4
```

In my query, I want to return Text4, because it is new.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myLog
WHERE eventDate > '2017-03-28 00:00:00'
AND  entryText LIKE 'Text%'
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM myLog
WHERE entryText LIKE 'Text%'
AND eventDate > '2017-03-27 00:00:00'
AND eventDate < '2017-03-28 00:00:00'
```

This query is returning nothing--is there a way I can do this type of query on a text field?

Comment: You can make these values into a list of values for sure and check if its not in the list of values by splitting the string separating by certain values, like commas.

Comment: Does `entryText` holds multiple values?

Comment: The text datatype has been deprecated in favor of varchar(max) since 2005...perhaps you need to stop using the text datatype.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple values in entryText.

Comment: Well, you better do two things: 1: normalize your database. 2: Stop using the `Text` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I see.  You want to compare the *exact* text in the later period to the earlier period.  You just need a correlation clause:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM myLog l
WHERE l.eventDate >= '2017-03-28' AND l. entryText LIKE 'Text%' AND
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM myLog l2
                 WHERE l2.entryText = l.EntryText AND
                       l2.eventDate >= '2017-03-27' AND
                       l2.eventDate < '2017-03-28'
                );
```

I suspect there is an issue with your data.  One possibility is that `eventDate` is actually a `date` with no time component.  If so, the subquery would return no rows, because you used `> '2017-03-27'`.

Comment: I checked, the eventDate is a datetime column. I am getting Test1-3 in the subquery and Test1-4 in the main query. This is mysterious.

Comment: How does NOT EXISTS know to compare the entryText column?

Comment: @JeanneLane . . . I think your comment clarified the question.  You need a correlation clause in the subquery.

Comment: Only with 

         l2.entryText LIKE l.EntryText

Answer (score 2):

I dont understand your problem but this query can be written well as

```
SELECT *
FROM myLog ml
WHERE eventDate > '2017-03-28 00:00:00'
AND  entryText LIKE 'Text%'
AND ml.idField not in 
(SELECT idField
FROM myLog
WHERE entryText LIKE 'Text%'
AND eventDate > '2017-03-27 00:00:00'
AND eventDate < '2017-03-28 00:00:00'
)
```

or you can  left join two tables and get the desired result as as

```
    SELECT *
    FROM myLog m1
    WHERE eventDate > '2017-03-28 00:00:00'
    AND  entryText LIKE 'Text%'

    left join
    (SELECT *
    FROM myLog
    WHERE entryText LIKE 'Text%'
    AND eventDate > '2017-03-27 00:00:00'
    AND eventDate < '2017-03-28 00:00:00'
    ) m2 on m1.idField =m2.IdField

where m1.idField is null
```

Comment: text fields don't allow "NOT IN"

Comment: I strongly discourage the use of `NOT IN` with subqueries.  Although probably correct in this case, if *any* rows in the subquery returns a `NULL` value, then the `WHERE` clause *never* evaluates to true.  That is not usually the intended logic.

Comment: ok if you discourgae not in then you can join table as my second option

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of questions that need to be answered for a full solution, but I will address them as best as I can and make a solution effort.

**Assumptions**

The `MyLog`table has a common identifier field other than the text field. This can be used to identify which record's text fields should be compared, rather than examining *all* text fields for matches.

Data is only appended to the text field. It is never removed (something like a running log of interactions).

If either of these assumptions is incorrect, please correct me.

**Questions**

What is the specific version of SQL Server being used in this case? SQL Server 2000 and prior will not work with the solution before.

**Solution**

The simplest way to do this is to cast the text field to a varchar(MAX) field for all comparisons. This allows a NOT IN construct if needed. In addition, you may want to use a CTE to simplify your querying, especially since a comparison on a text field is inefficient, e.g.

```
;WITH RecsToCheck as (
    SELECT 
        RecIDField, 
        CommonField,
        OtherField, 
        eventDate, 
        Cast(entryText as varchar(MAX)) as entryText
    FROM myLog
    WHERE eventDate > '2017-03-27 00:00:00'
        AND entryText LIKE 'Text%'
    )
SELECT *
FROM RecsToCheck rc1
LEFT JOIN RecsToCheck rc2
    ON rc1.CommonField=rc2.CommonField
    AND rc1.entryText != rc2.entryText
WHERE rc1.eventDate < '20170327'
    AND rc2.eventDate >= '20170328'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got text4 to come up this way...

```
SELECT *
FROM myLog l1
WHERE l1.eventDate > '2017-03-28 00:00:00'
AND  l1.entryText LIKE 'Text%'
AND CAST(l1.entryText as varchar(8000) NOT IN
(SELECT CAST(l2.entryText as varchar(8000)
FROM myLog l2
WHERE l2.entryText LIKE 'Text%'
AND l2.eventDate > '2017-03-27 00:00:00'
AND l2.eventDate < '2017-03-28 00:00:00')
```

Not sure if it will break in the future...